# LogManager.configuration is null

Tags: c#, nlog

I've added NLog using nuget to a project and added NLog.config.  I'm running the debugger and getting a `NullReferenceException` due to the fact `LogManager.Configuration` is null:

`LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget("sentinel", sentinalTarget);`

This line of code runs in a static constructor.

- NLog.config is located in the project root alongside the web.config.
- This occurs in visual studio debugger
- NLog.config property "Copy to output directory" = "Copy Always"
- I updated NLog.config throwExceptions="true" and at runtime `LogManager.ThrowExceptions` was false so I suspect an issue with the config
- Tried removing the targets with name: viewer, DbWin and their associated rules

NLog.config contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="false">

  <variable name="appName" value="YourAppName" />

  <targets async="true">
    <target xsi:type="File"
            name="default"
            layout="${longdate} - ${level:uppercase=true}: ${message}${onexception:${newline}EXCEPTION\: ${exception:format=ToString}}"
            fileName="${specialfolder:ApplicationData}\${appName}\Debug.log"
            keepFileOpen="false"
            archiveFileName="${specialfolder:ApplicationData}\${appName}\Debug_${shortdate}.{##}.log"
            archiveNumbering="Sequence"
            archiveEvery="Day"
            maxArchiveFiles="30"
            />

    <target xsi:type="EventLog"
            name="eventlog"
            source="${appName}"
            layout="${message}${newline}${exception:format=ToString}"/>

    <target xsi:type="NLogViewer"
            name="viewer"
            address="udp://127.0.0.1:9999"/>

    <target xsi:type="OutputDebugString" name="DbWin" layout="Log4JXmlEventLayout">
      <layout xsi:type="Log4JXmlEventLayout" />
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" writeTo="default" minlevel="Info" />
    <logger name="*" writeTo="eventlog" minlevel="Error" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="viewer" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="DbWin" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

**Update**
I discovered the source.  The issue occurs only when running unit tests.  Running the full application (web app) the issue is not there.  I copied the NLog.config file to the unit test home directory.  The issue is still there when running unit tests.

Comment: I'm sure that you've tried simpler NLog configurations (like just going to a file), but I'll ask anyway.  Also, is it possible that the static constructor where you are adding the target to the Configuration object executes before the NLog.config file is read?

Comment: @wageoghe Yes, the issue is narrowed down.  See update

Comment: Assuming you are using Microsoft's unit testing framework, you might need to make the NLog.config file a DeploymentItem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

- Copy NLog.config to the Test projects top level folder
- Add `DeploymentItemAttribute` to test classes ([more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475%28VS.80%29.aspx))

Like this:

```
[TestClass]
[DeploymentItem("ProjectName\\NLog.config")]
public class GeneralTests
```

Alternatively, you can load the configuration programmatically:

`LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(@"c:\path\to\NLog.config")`

Comment: To set the configuration programatically,declare `var config = new LoggingConfiguration()`, set the properties of `config`, then set `LogManager.Configuration = config`.

Comment: LogManager.Configuration = new XmlLoggingConfiguration(@".\\NLog.config") works for me. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your nlog.config is in one of the folders NLog scans to look for the config file. For example the folder of your executable.

If you are using Visual Studio, you can configure it like this to automate the copy process:
[image]

Comment: NLog scans multiple file-locations to find its configuration: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#file-locations

Comment: Thanks, I updated the answer to be more precise.